# Hide second device created by camera in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, usb, camera, device-manager

When I plug my camera in via USB, two devices open their autoplay dialogue and two devices show up in My Computer.

[image: Screenshot of devices]

`Removable Disk (H:)` is the correct device for locating my photographs, but I am also stuck with `PMHOME (F:)` always showing up. It just contains some shortcuts to web pages and nothing useful.

Is there a way to permanently hide or disable that device in Windows 7?

Comment: Have you tried going to Disk Management (`Start > Run > diskmgmt.msc`) and removing that drive letter?

Comment: Would also be my first idea...